# When we translate a text from one language to another, how does the frequency of various POS tags change?

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, language-model, pos-tagging

When we translate a text from one language to another, how does the frequency of various POS tags change?

So, let's say we have a text in English, with 10% nouns, 20% adjectives, 15% adverbs, 25% verbs, etc., which we now translate to German, French, or Hindi. Can we say that in these other languages the POS tag frequency will remain the same as earlier?